Why do I have to import the same class/package twice to files in the same folder?
All right so basically, I'm trying to import java.util.*. However, I have to do this at the top of every file I create (which are all in the same folder), and I'm looking for a way to reduce the redundancy and just import it to all of them like how java.lang and everything else is. Is there a way to do this?
It's forcing me to write this but tried to import it to a file that was in the folder containing the folder that my actual files were in and it didn't work.
